# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'glassdoor' while creating a user object from custom user model

Tags: python, django

I have a custom user model called User. I tried to populate some data. I successfully created a superuser. However, when I try to create a normal user, this Error appears:" ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'glassdoor'" where glassdoor is the password. Anyone know how to fix this?

In my custom user model, I only made email as my login requirements and omit username, also added some other attributes. I did not override default django password settings.

models.py

```py
class User(AbstractUser):

    #use email as authentication
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    objects = CustomUserManager()
    # id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
      (1, 'doctor'),
      (2, 'labPeople'),
      (3, 'receptionist'),
      (4, 'patient'),
      (5, 'admin'),
    )
    user_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES,null=True)
    sex = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    tel_no = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    dob = models.DateField(db_column='DOB', blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['user_type',]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

managers.py for managing my custom user model

```py
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.db import models
import django



class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Custom user model manager where email is the unique identifiers
    for authentication instead of usernames.
    """
    use_in_migrations = True
    def _create_user(self, email, user_type, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a User with the given email and password.
        """
        django.setup()
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The Email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, user_type=user_type, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, user_type, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a regular User with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        if user_type in set([1,2,3,5]):
            is_staff = True
        return self._create_user(email, password, user_type, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, user_type, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.
        """
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')
        return self._create_user(email, password, user_type, **extra_fields)
```

The error occurs when I try to execute this line of code:

```py
doc = User.objects.create_user(email='jlennon@beatles.com',password='glassdoor',user_type=1)
```

Below is the file trace:

```py
Starting healthDB population script...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "populate_health.py", line 90, in <module>
    populate()
  File "populate_health.py", line 25, in populate
    doc = User.objects.create_user(email='jlennon@beatles.com',password='glassdoor',user_type=1)
  File "/Users/linda_xiong/Workspace/myhealth/health/managers.py", line 33, in create_user
    return self._create_user(email, password, user_type, **extra_fields)
  File "/Users/linda_xiong/Workspace/myhealth/health/managers.py", line 24, in _create_user
    user.save(using=self._db)
  File "//anaconda/envs/myhealth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 66, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "//anaconda/envs/myhealth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 741, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "//anaconda/envs/myhealth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 779, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "//anaconda/envs/myhealth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 870, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "//anaconda/envs/myhealth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 908, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "//anaconda/envs/myhealth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "//anaconda/envs/myhealth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1186, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "//anaconda/envs/myhealth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1334, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "//anaconda/envs/myhealth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1278, in as_sql
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "//anaconda/envs/myhealth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1278, in <listcomp>
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "//anaconda/envs/myhealth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1277, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "//anaconda/envs/myhealth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1218, in prepare_value
    value = field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=self.connection)
  File "//anaconda/envs/myhealth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 789, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "//anaconda/envs/myhealth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 784, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "//anaconda/envs/myhealth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1819, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'glassdoor'
```

What cause this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `create_user()` function is passing the wrong arguments to `_create_user()`.  `user_type` is supposed to be the second argument, but you're sending `password` as the second argument by mistake.